# Intuitionism and circles

Tags: soft-question

I know next to nothing about intuitionism, so my question is probably silly :)

As I understand from Wikipedia, intuitionism (at least finitism) doesn't 'trust' in the existence of irrational numbers, because they cannot be constructed (at least in finite number of steps). How does it deal with circles then? Or, even better, how does it deal with bilateral right triangles? Do such things exist in this framework? Do metric concepts exist at all?

Comment: Circles can be constructed in a finite amount of steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Constructive mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_%28mathematics%29) allows irrational numbers and much more, including of course circles. See the books by [Bishop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errett_Bishop) and his followers on [constructive analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_analysis). Constructivism is often identified with intuitionism but it's not the same thing. See also this [review](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/19/?pa=reviews&sa=viewBook&bookId=67400) of a book by Bridger.

Comment: Likewise, finitism is orthogonal to intuitionism (even though there are common directions in skepticism of mainstream mathematical methods).

Answer (score 3):

“Heyting. Intuitionism: An introduction.” (a Russian translation is also available) constructs real numbers.